# Proof for $\int_{S^n(r)} \, dx=\int_{S^n(1)}r^n \, dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I read the wikipedia article about [$n$-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere). I'm trying to give a proof for the following formula
$$
\int_{S^n(r)}dx=\int_{S^n(1)}r^ndx,\tag{*}
$$
where $S^n(r):=\{x\in {\Bbb R}^{n+1}:|x|=r\}$ for $r>0$.

---

When $n=2$ and $n=3$, there is no problem. But I don't see how to generalize it to the general cases. 
I tried to use the definition of [surface integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral), but I don't see how it could help. One might want to use change of variable to get
$$
\int_{B^{n+1}(r)}dx=\int_{B^{n+1}(1)}r^{n+1}dx,
$$
and then use the relation between $\int_{B^{n+1}(r)}dx$ and $\int_{S^n(r)}dx$ which is asked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/644203/9464). But then it would boil down to showing  $(*)$. How should I prove that formula?

Comment: change of variables formula, its just scaling

Comment: A more fundamental question to ask about ($*$) could have been what is the *definition* of the "surface integrals" $\int_{S^n(r)}\,dx$ and $\int_{S^n(1)}r^n\,dx$. Once is absolutely clear, a proof for ($*$) should be immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beatween heuristic and intuitive:

First, in $\mathbb R^n$,
$$
\int_{|x|<r}dx=r^n\int_{|x|<1}dx,
$$
which is due to the property of Lebesgue measure: $m(rE)=r^nm(E)$.

Then
$$
\int_{|x|=r}dx=\frac{d}{dr}\int_{|x|<r}dx=\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^n\int_{|x|<1}dx\right)=nr^{n-1}\int_{|x|<1}dx. \tag{1}
$$
For $r=1$ in the above we have
$$
\int_{|x|=1}dx=n\int_{|x|<1}dx. \tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
\int_{|x|=r}dx=r^{n-1}\int_{|x|=1}dx.
$$
You only have to believe that
$$
\int_{|x|=r}dx=\frac{d}{dr}\int_{|x|<r}dx.
$$